# How to transform a decision tree for binary classification to a decision tree for multi-label classification?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, decision-tree, multilabel-classification

I want to adapt a decision tree algorithm that works for two tags: True/False to one that can decide on multiple tags.

```
data = [({'Age': 1, 'Quartier': 'A', 'Income': 10}, 'PartyB'),
 ({'Age': 2, 'Quartier': 'B', 'Income': 20}, "PartyA"),
 ({'Age': 3, 'Quartier': 'C', 'Income': 30}, 'ABS'),
 ({'Age': 4, 'Quartier': 'D', 'Income': 40}, 'ABS')]
```

I want to be able to predict the etiquette of the following: `{'Age': 1, 'Quartier': 'A', 'Income': 15}`
Yet, I

## My attempt

```
def classify(tree, input):
    """classify the input using the given decision tree"""
    if tree in [True,False]: # here I need to change to adapt it to multiple categories.
        return tree

    # otherwise this tree consists of an attribute to split on
    # and a dictionnary whose keys are values of that attribute
    # and whose values of are subtrees to consider next
    print("tree: ", tree)
    print("df.TL_Segment.unique(): ",df.TL_Segment.unique())
    attribute, subtree_dict = tree

    subtree_key = input.get(attribute) # None if input is missing in attribute

    if subtree_key not in subtree_dict: # if no subtree for key
        subtree_key = None

    subtree = subtree_dict[subtree_key]
    return classify(subtree, input)

from functools import partial
from statistics import mode

def build_tree_id3(inputs, split_candidates = None):
    # if this is our first pass
    # all keys of the first input are split candidates

    if split_candidates is None:
        split_candidates = inputs[0][0].keys()

    # count different classes
    num_inputs = len(inputs)
    num_different_classes = len(set([label for item, label in inputs if label]))

    if num_different_classes == 1: return False # only one class? Return this one
    if num_different_classes == num_inputs: return False# all classes are different? 

    if not split_candidates: 
        return max(set(inputs), key = inputs.count)

    # otherwise, split on the best attribute
    best_attribute = min(split_candidates, key = partial(partition_entropy_by,inputs))

    partitions = partition_by(inputs, best_attribute)
    new_candidates = [a for a in split_candidates
                     if a!= best_attribute]

    #recursively build the subtrees 
    subtrees = {attribute_value: build_tree_id3(subset, new_candidates)
               for attribute_value,
                subset in partitions.items()}

#   subtrees[None] = max(inputs, key=collections.Counter(inputs).get) # if tree is empty we give the most frequent one
    subtrees[None] = None

    return(best_attribute, subtrees)
```

But when I try I get "False", not the categories:

```
tree = build_tree_id3(data)
```

returns:

```
best_attribute:  Age
subtrees:  {1: False, 2: False, 3: False, 4: False, None: None}
```

pero `classify(tree, {'Age': 1, 'Quartier': 'A', 'Income': 10})` devuelve:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-462-86da50b80bb6> in <module>
----> 1 classify(tree, {'Age': 1, 'Quartier': 'A', 'Income': 10})

<ipython-input-453-9dce8ec72645> in classify(tree, input)
     15 
     16     subtree = subtree_dict[subtree_key]
---> 17     return classify(subtree, input)
     18 

<ipython-input-453-9dce8ec72645> in classify(tree, input)
      7     # and a dictionnary whose keys are values of that attribute
      8     # and whose values of are subtrees to consider next
----> 9     attribute, subtree_dict = tree
     10 
     11     subtree_key = input.get(attribute) # None if input is missing in attribute

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable bool object
```

Indeed, `tree` is `False` here.

## Annex: Other function used here

```
import math
import collections

def entropy(class_probabilities):
    """given a list of class probabilities, compute the entropy"""
    return sum(-p * math.log(p,2)
              for p in class_probabilities
              if p)

def class_probabilities(labels):
    total_count = len(labels)
    return [count / total_count
           for count in collections.Counter(labels).values()]

def data_entropy(labeled_data):
    labels = [label for _,label in labeled_data]
    probabilities = class_probabilities(labels)
    return entropy(probabilities)

def partition_entropy(subsets):
    """find entropy from this partition of data into subsets
    subsets is a list of lists of labeled data"""
    total_count =sum(len(subset) for subset in subsets)
    return sum(data_entropy(subset)* len(subset)/total_count
              for subset in subsets)

def partition_by(inputs, attribute):
    """each input is a pair (attriute_dict,label).
    returns a dict : attribute_value -> inputs"""
    groups = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for input in inputs:
        key = input[0][attribute] # get the value of the specified attribute
        groups[key].append(input) # then add this input to the correct list
    return groups

def partition_entropy_by(inputs, attribute):
    """computes the entropy corresponding to the given partition"""
    partitions = partition_by(inputs, attribute)
    return partition_entropy(partitions.values())
```

Comment: Your goal is to build your own class? If not, then multi-class classification is already supported here. See http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html

Comment: @null Yes, to build my own class. It helps me understand it better